# Reading image files in a given directory in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert all images in a folder to gray. That's my code and I get this error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
>   'cv::cvtColor'

```py
import cv2
import os

path = r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\computerVision\CarDetection_withOpenCV\p'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full path to file

**Ex:**

```
import cv2
import os

path = r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\computerVision\CarDetection_withOpenCV\p'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```